# Snowflake COPY INTO column from CSV

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Ok so I'm having some trouble working through the syntax of the **COPY INTO** command.

I have 2 CSV Files with one column each in S3:

- **phone.csv** contains phone numbers with the header **phone**
- **zip.csv** contains zip codes with the header **zip**

I am trying to use the **COPY INTO** command to copy the contents of these 2 files into the the table **clientinputs** in the respective **phone** and **zip** columns.

Since I am creating a python 3x function to accomplish this I need 1 query that I can repurpose with variables so that I can import the data from **phone.csv** and then call the function again to import the data from **zip.csv**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which query did you try?

Comment: @Kirk Holmes What is the column constraint for the column Phone and Zip in the table - clientinputs.

Is the column is null or not null.

Many Thanks, Sriga

Comment: Are you loading the files into a stage first before attempting any kind of transformative COPY INTO?  Data loading transformation only supports selecting data from user stages and named stages (internal or external).  Then you can select the columns from one file explicitly and where to insert them in the target table.  Additionally, please see the docs here for syntax examples:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#transforming-csv-data

Comment: @SuzyLockwood that documentation worked perfectly!

Comment: @KirkHolmes Great to hear!  Let me repost my comment as an answer then so it can be more easily seen by those who may have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Data loading transformation only supports selecting data from user stages and named stages (internal or external). Once the data is in a stage, then you can select the columns from one file explicitly and where to insert them in the target table. Please see the docs here for syntax examples:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#transforming-csv-data